# Round CGPoint location

Tags: iphone, cgpoint

In my application I am developing a sort of tile system.  Instead of doing my tiles manually I am planning on having UIImageViews that "snap" to a specific location.

Here's my question:

How can I round my new location to a factor of (in my case) 16?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Same as how you would do with individual `float` values.

```
CGPoint snap(CGPoint p) {
  return CGPointMake(roundf(p.x / 16) * 16,
                     roundf(p.y / 16) * 16);
}
```